# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout'

Tags: matplotlib, grid, subplot, layoutsubviews

I am trying to run the code which is one of example on matplotlib and I didnt change anything. BUt it gives me an error:"**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout'"

CODE:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


def format_axes(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)

fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")

gs = GridSpec(3, 3, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
# identical to ax1 = plt.subplot(gs.new_subplotspec((0, 0), colspan=3))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :-1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, 0])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, -2])

fig.suptitle("GridSpec")
format_axes(fig)

plt.show()
```

(https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-multicolumn-py)

I got this error recently before it was working.

Any solution?

I just run the code in jupyter notebook latest version.

Comment: Are you using the same matplotlib version as in the tutorial?

Comment: import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.__version__)
3.3.2

Comment: Your documentation is from matplotlib 3.8.3